# GeoKettle - inserting geometry into a table

Tags: shapefile, geometry, geokettle

I've got some shapefiles, and need to convert the shapes into an SQL Geometry type and insert them into a table in our database. We're using GeoKettle.

I can open the shapefile find and read values in from it into the table (such as a text field in the shapefile into a varchar in the table), but don't know the steps I need to translate the shape, which appears to be coming out of the shapefile as WKT, into a geometry.

Basically, whenever I execute, I get the error that it doesn't seem to be able to insert it. Which is understandable, as I say it seems to be coming out as WKT and trying to insert that into a geometry field. And I know the method to convert it to geometry in SQL (STGeomFromText) - I just essentially need to know how to add that in GeoKettle.

Comment: Related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62315/how-to-use-geokettle-to-load-shapefiles-into-oracle-spatial

Comment: Tried that, not working. It's coming up with a java.lang.ClassCastException - which it shouldn't really be doing as it's just taking the geometry from the shapefile input (the_geom) and trying to save it to the table's geometry field.

Comment: What database are you using?  GeoKettle just takes the shapefile geometry and feeds into PostGIS for me.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily "the" answer but a way around - just used an "Execute SQL script" control to insert each one. Bit of a pain but it works.